# Deserialize Json object from WCF RESTful Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have WCF RESTful Service declaration as below

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetJson/{id}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
EmployeeJSON GetEmployeeJSON(string id);
```

I get `EmployeeJSON` object from WCF RESTful Service as below

```
public EmployeeJSON GetEmployeeJSON(string id)
    {
        List<EmployeeJSON> employees = new List<EmployeeJSON>()
        {
             new EmployeeJSON() {Name="Sumanth",Id=101,Salary=5000.00 },
             new EmployeeJSON() {Name="Ehsan",Id=102,Salary=6000.00 },
        };

        var Employee = (from x in employees
                        where x.Id.ToString() == id
                        select x);


        return Employee.FirstOrDefault() as EmployeeJSON;
    }
```

I call the WCF RESTful service from client as below

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:1249/Service1.svc/GetJson/101");
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

And I get `json` value as follows

```
{"GetEmployeeJSONResult":{"Id":101,"Name":"Sumanth","Salary":5000}}
```

Now I am trying to Deserialize the above `json` as follows

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Employee responseObject = serializer.Deserialize<Employee>(json);
```

The Employee class structure is as follows at client side...

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
}
```

But the result I am getting is `Id as 0, Name as null and Salary as 0.0`

How can I deserialize the `JSON` object?

Comment: Your JSON string describes an Object with one Property:```GetEmployeeJSONResult```, which is an ```Employee``` Object:```public class tempObject{public Employee GetEmployeeJSONResult{get;set;}}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Employee class didnt match the structure of the JSON string.
This class is:

```
public class EmployeeContainer
{
        public Employee GetEmployeeJSONResult { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
Employee responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeContainer>(json)?.GetEmployeeJSONResult;
```

Comment: Can you please remove question mark in the second code?

Comment: What could be the code if the WCF RESTful service returns List of Employees here?

Comment: The ? is for preventing a NullReferenceException
And yes, if you provide a example JSON string with the List data, I could adjust the code.